# How to fetch a string from https of multiple layers in gmail using google scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, urlfetch

I am trying to fetch a string from a link in gmail. the link is https, which has multiple redirect for security purpose as using third party service.

Link#1 in gmail --redirect-> Link#2 --redirect-> Link#3

Now the string is hidden in the content of Link#3. Tried using UrlFetchApp, but https didn't work for me. Or maybe it's the way the redirect work.

How do I achieve this goal? Can anyone shed some light?

p.s. my first post, sorry if my tags wrong.

Comment: Set `followRedirects` to `true`

Comment: "it didn't work" ... Well, how can we know what was wrong? Show your attempt.

Comment: Can you put the error message you're getting and the response for the request please.

Comment: Could you please share an example link with that that goes through the progression of Link1 > Link2 > Link3, along with the text you're trying to fetch?